# Errors in XML schema from MOXy

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I'm trying to generate an XML schema using JAXBContext.generateSchema(..).

My class looks something like this:

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
class Person {
  @XmlAttribute
  public String name;

  @XmlAnyAttribute
  public Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();
}
```

And when I generate the schema using the RI, it works fine.

```xml
<xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:anyAttribute processContents="skip" namespace="##other" />
```

But when using the generator from MOXy, it switches the order:

```xml
<xsd:anyAttribute processContents="skip" namespace="##other" />
<xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
```

(this is not allowed in XML schema)

Is there a fix for this? I'm using MOXy 2.4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

I have entered the following bug for this issue which you can use to track our progress on this issue.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/397126

We should have a fix in early in the new year once everyone is back from vacation.

**UPDATE**

This issue has been fixed in the EclipseLink 2.4.2 and 2.5.0 streams.  Any of the nightly builds for these labels starting Dec 28 2012 will contain this fix and are available from the following link:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

Comment: Thank you, wasn't 100% sure if it was a bug or not. Just ask if you need the full code (it isn't much).